# Rails not passing nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a clone link for my Miniatures model. I want it to copy the current model and render a NEW form filled in with the current model's info so it can be tweaked slightly and then saved.

I'm linking with:

```
<%= link_to 'clone', clone_miniature_path(@miniature) %>
```

I have the following action in my miniatures_controller:

```
    def clone
        @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id]) # find original object
        @miniature = Miniature.new(@miniature.attributes) # initialize duplicate (not saved)
        @all_manufacturers = Manufacturer.all
        @production = @miniature.productions.build
        render :new # render same view as "new", but with @miniature attributes already filled in
    end
```

**UPDATE:** I've now defined @production as above and it no longer crashes during the render but it only fills in the form with the @miniature model information and leaves the @production drop-down blank. Might I need to add something to the line:

```
@miniature = Miniature.new(@miniature.attributes)
```

perhaps? Strange since miniature_params certainly includes the productions_attributes: needed to fill in the drop down. Works fine in edit view.

My new method is

```
def new
    @miniature = Miniature.new 
    @all_manufacturers = Manufacturer.all
    @production = @miniature.productions.build
end
```

My edit method is pretty much the same but obviously with a find.

Comment: You've not defined `@production`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your model, but if a Miniature has a Production relationship, you should have someting like:

```
<%= f.fields_for(@miniature.production) do |pf|%>
```

You are refereing @production which you do not define in your controller. Maybe something like

```
def clone
    @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id]) # find original object
    @miniature = Miniature.new(@miniature.attributes) # initialize duplicate (not saved)
    @production = @minitature.production
    render :new # render same view as "new", but with @miniature attributes already filled in
end
```

Could help.

Again, not sure of the relationship between "production" and "miniature".

Comment: Ah I had thought that since it then renders new it would have all the things defined in my NEW action but is it just rendering the NEW view?

Comment: Yep, render does not execute anything in the referenced controller - it just render the related template. If you want to execute the code in the new action, that make it more like a "redirect" - or you can just extract the common code in a private method inside your controller.

Comment: Aha! Pasted all the definitions from my NEW method into the CLONE method and it no longer crashes. It still isn't filling in the fields for the associated models. They are drop downs and they are just blank right now.

Comment: Can you post the code of your "new" method. Is it working there? Or are the value linked to the "production" model ?

Comment: New and Edit work perfectly. I've added the NEW method above.

Comment: I think your "render" should be the last line of the clone method.

Comment: Sorry, it is. I just copy pasted it in the wrong order here. Will edit.

Comment: You can call the 'new' method before you call `render :new`.

Comment: Would that help, Swards?